# Convert value to number format in Flutter input?

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, decimal, textinput

I have a problem with Flutter InputTextField. I'm developing an app like CashApp were you have a feature which you can send money to other people.

The problem is: I need to achieve a **number format** and **allow only two decimals**.

For example, if I enter:

- "1000,25" -> It needs to transform to 1.000,25
- "10000,25" -> It needs to transform to 10.000,25

And so on..

I've been using this code to reach the only two decimals part

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class DecimalTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  DecimalTextInputFormatter({this.decimalRange, this.activatedNegativeValues})
      : assert(decimalRange == null || decimalRange >= 0,
            'DecimalTextInputFormatter declaretion error');

  final int decimalRange;
  final bool activatedNegativeValues;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue, // unused.
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    TextSelection newSelection = newValue.selection;
    String truncated = newValue.text;


if (newValue.text.contains(' ')) {
  return oldValue;
}

if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
  return newValue;
} else if (double.tryParse(newValue.text) == null &&
    !(newValue.text.length == 1 &&
        (activatedNegativeValues == true ||
            activatedNegativeValues == null) &&
        newValue.text == '-')) {
  return oldValue;
}

if (activatedNegativeValues == false &&
    double.tryParse(newValue.text) < 0) {
  return oldValue;
}

if (decimalRange != null) {
  String value = newValue.text;

  if (decimalRange == 0 && value.contains(".")) {
    truncated = oldValue.text;
    newSelection = oldValue.selection;
  }

  if (value.contains(".") &&
      value.substring(value.indexOf(".") + 1).length > decimalRange) {
    truncated = oldValue.text;
    newSelection = oldValue.selection;
  } else if (value == ".") {
    truncated = "0.";

    newSelection = newValue.selection.copyWith(
      baseOffset: math.min(truncated.length, truncated.length + 1),
      extentOffset: math.min(truncated.length, truncated.length + 1),
    );
  }

  return TextEditingValue(
    text: truncated,
    selection: newSelection,
    composing: TextRange.empty,
  );
}
return newValue;
}
}
```

This is a response I found from this [post](http://%20%5B1%5D:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454983/allow-only-two-decimal-number-in-flutter-input/57470270#57470270)

This code almost do the thing. It restrict the two decimals part, but doesn't have the NumberFormat part, and instead of 'commas' for the decimals, it uses 'dots'.

I want to swap the '.' for thousands and ',' for decimals. And add the NumberFormat too.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for locale Brazil? Then the number currency format of Brazil could be set in you DecimalTextInputFormatter class to achieve the same result.

Comment: Not Brazil, but Argentina. I can change the locale to ARG.

In which part of the class I have to paste your part? Can you give me a full example if its not a problem please? Thanks!

Comment: I've added it as a new Class. But I cant input anything, just one number :/. Its like it get stucked